# Loop to fill boxes with text objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a game of "pick the color not the word" in Python.
There is a list of 9 different colors:

```
cnames = [" green ", " blue ", " yellow ", " gray ", " pink ", " orange ", " purple ", " red ", " brown "]
```

I have written a function which randomizes these colors:

```
def randomize():
    import random
    cnames=["green", "blue","yellow", "grey", "pink", "orange", "Purple", "red", "brown"]
    color=randint(0, len (cnames)-1)
    cname=randint(0, len(cnames)-1)

    from random import sample
    other_cnames=random.sample(range(len(cnames)),6)

    return (color, cname, other_cnames)
```

The code for the game window is:

```
win=GraphWin("New_game", 800,800)
    color, cname, other_names=randomize()

    rcname=cnames[cname]
    rcname=rcname [0].upper() + rcname[1:]
    target=Text(Point(300,100),rcname)
    target.setOutline(cnames[color])
    target.setStyle ("bold")
    target.setSize(24)
    target.draw(win)

    Boxes=[]
    k=0
```

How do I make a loop that fills the list boxes with text objects, where each text object is representing a color and the number of the color (0 to 8)?

the result should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for statement to iterate code a number of times to fill boxes like:

`for x in range(*insert number of boxes*):
     *put other code here*`

This will fill it up if you just put the range in

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you have asked for, assuming you want to return color and color list without the color selected.

```
cnames = ['green', 'blue'...]
```

to pick one color from list use random.choice

```
color = random.choice(cnames)
```

to get other colors init new list and pop by index

```
other_colors = list(cnames)
other_colors.pop(colors.index(color))
```

return selected color and others

```
return color, other_colors
```

in graphwin

```
color, other_colors = randomize()

ucolor = '{0}{1}'.format(color[0].upper(), color[1:])
target = Text(Point(300,100),ucolor)
target.setOutline(color)
...
Boxes = other_colors #
```